# Flex Tooltip Positioning in a Resizeable App

Tags: apache-flex, tooltip

Our Flex app automatically resizes with the browser window, we've addressed a whole bunch of scaling issues quite easily but one that remains is tooltips. They show in the wrong location on screen, not being scaled properly based on the window size. Since tooltips are positioned automatically, how can we address this?

To clarify I am using the built-in flex tooltips. And the problem is not that tooltips don't move as the app resizes when they are shown. It's that if I resize the app, tooltips will now all be shown in the wrong place even through everything else automatically updates correctly.

Comment: Are you using the built-in tooltips or your own?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you found a solution to this one, but there's a simpler approach.  This code hooks into the tooltip-show event, during the capture phase (before it displays), to scale and position it appropriately based on the scale of the containing element -- in "this" case, the `parentApplication` document.  It also includes a bit of code that, in my case, helped keep the tooltips from drifting off the stage when scaled (so you might only need the first few lines -- `t.scaleX` and `t.scaleY`):

```
import mx.events.ToolTipEvent;

addEventListener(ToolTipEvent.TOOL_TIP_SHOW, handleToolTipShow, true, 0, true);

private function handleToolTipShow(event:ToolTipEvent):void
{
    if (event && event.toolTip)
    {
        var t:IToolTip = event.toolTip;

        // Scale the tip itself
        t.scaleX = this.scaleX;
        t.scaleY = this.scaleY;

        // Scale the offsets
        var xOffset:int = 10 * this.scaleX;
        var yOffset:int = 10 * this.scaleY;

        // Set the default positioning 
        t.x = parent.mouseX + xOffset;
        t.y = parent.mouseY + yOffset;

        // Set the adjusted height and width
        var th:Number = t.height * this.scaleX;
        var tw:Number = t.width * this.scaleY;

        var rightEdge:int = t.x + tw + xOffset;
        var playerRightEdge:int = parent.width;
        var bottomEdge:int = t.y + th + yOffset;
        var playerBottomEdge:int = parent.height;

        // Offscreen right
        if (rightEdge > playerRightEdge)
        {
            t.move(parent.mouseX - xOffset - tw, parent.mouseY + yOffset);
        }

        // Offscreen bottom
        if (bottomEdge > playerBottomEdge)
        {
            t.move(parent.mouseX + xOffset, parent.mouseY - yOffset - th);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a great solution to this problem since the `ToolTipManager` is not aware of when the `currentTarget` for a `ToolTip` changes location on the stage.  The fix pretty much has to go into the Flex Framework itself.  I have cludged together something that seems to work but it requires monkeypatching the Flex Framework.

1. Copy `mx.managers.ToolTipManager.as` into your project in a `mx.managers` package you create.
2. Add this method to the bottom of the file.

   ```
   public static function positionToolTip() : void {
       ToolTipManagerImpl(impl).positionTip();
   }
   ```
3. Call this method on the resize event of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the coordinates to Global using contentToGlobal()

Answer (score 0):

http://strutsforflex.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-set-custom-tooltipmanager.html
much more simple